# Set the MaskType of TextEdit as Boolean

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, textedit

I have a TextEdit in my DevExpress Xtragrid.

I want to set the Mask Type of TextEdit as Boolean

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it easier and event a better solution to implement a Combobox in your XtraGrid?
A detailed example on Comboboxes in Xtragrid can be found [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A122.aspx).